# jQuery animations break after some time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I stay in my div the animation won't work again if I go out and in again... So like when I stay in the field while the animation is playing when I quit and go back in it again, it doesn't start the animation over again..

HTML:

```
<div class="ani-bounce-slow" style="height: 200px; width: 50%; background-color: #3c3; ">
    <p> This is a bouncing Text!</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bounce-slow {
animation: bounce 3s;
}

@keyframes bounce {
    0%,
    20%,
    50%,
    80%,
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    40% {
        transform: translateY(-30px);
    }
    60% {
        transform: translateY(-15px);
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.ani-bounce-slow').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).addClass('bounce-slow');
});
$('.ani-bounce-slow').one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend',
    function (e) {
        $(this).removeClass('bounce-slow');
    }
);
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/otor7ry4/2/)

Comment: So you want is every time you enter div it should bounce, but only once? After you leave and come back for hover it again bounces, for only once while you on it. Right?

Comment: Yes, but when I stay in until the animation ends and then hover out and in again it won't start the animation again. @divy3993

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). That is how you mark a question as solved, not by changing the title.

Comment: @Quentin I did both dude. It's for people who have the same problem and they google it so they get this post starting with solved so they know the solution is here ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are using [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function instead of [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

Change:

```
$('.ani-bounce-slow').one('webkitAnimationEnd...
```

To:

```
$('.ani-bounce-slow').on('webkitAnimationEnd...
```

> .one( events [, data ], handler )
>     
>   Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed ***at most once*** per element per event type.
>
> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
>     
>   Attach an event handler function for ***one or more*** events to the selected elements.

Comment: He is right... one will only remove it the first time. The question was not super clear on what exactly needed to be adjusted, but I like this conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to rip out the class to stop the animation on leave, and just add it back on enter. This will make the animation happen every time.

```
$('.ani-bounce-slow').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).addClass('bounce-slow');
});
$('.ani-bounce-slow').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('bounce-slow');
});
```

If you want the animation to continue on mouse leave, then you need to check for animation completion, or set a timer for how loong the animation should be.